# SQL Server database splitting by purpose

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, database-design

Databases usually are a storage for most applications. Our company also makes a lot of calculations and data manipulations with that data on daily basis.

As soon as we get more and more data, data generation became an issue cause takes too long. And I think it can make sense to separate database to at least two :

- for storing data with focus on read/write performance;
- for calculations with focus on data aggregation performance.

Does anybody has similar experience and can tell if this idea is good and what will be design differences for mentioned two points?

Maybe it is worth to look for noSQL solution for calculating data e.g. in-memory databases?

Comment: Have a look at SQL SSAS for calculation and aggragation

Comment: @RegBes are you talking about adding measure calculations?  is it faster? I could try that ...

Comment: @RegBes not sure if it will work.. as don't have much experience with that. There couple of dozens of calculation steps in our generation. So I will need to create a chain of calc measures which depend one on previous one?

Comment: You could create a separate database with the calculations, in essence a data mart. Just write an ETL using SSIS. You can do the calculations, archive historical data and the like. We did something similar at a previous company and ran a monthly process that did archiving and new calculations on the latest month of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it can make sense to separate database to at least two

If the databases are in different Disks (with different spindles ), it may help otherwise you get no gain because disk IO is shared between these databases.

For best practice,read [Storage Top 10 Best Practices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966534.aspx)

> Maybe it is worth to look for noSQL solution for calculating data e.g. in-memory databases?

No need to go to noSQL solution, you can use in-memory tables 
In-Memory OLTP can significantly improve the performance of transaction processing,  data load and transient data scenarios.

For more details, [In-Memory OLTP (In-Memory Optimization)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/in-memory-oltp-in-memory-optimization)

**Other Strategies**

1) Tune tempdb

Tempdb is common for all databases and heavily used in calculations.

A more pragmatic approach, is to have a 1:1 mapping between files and logical CPUs(cores) up to eight.

for more details: [SQL Server TempDB Usage, Performance, and Tuning Tips](http://blog.directionstraining.com/microsoft-sql-server/sql-server-tempdb-usage-performance-and-tuning-tips)

2) Evaluate life expectancy (PLE) Counter and take actions for enhancement

To evaluate data cache, run the following query

```
    SELECT [object_name],
    [counter_name],
    [cntr_value] FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
    WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%Manager%'
    AND [counter_name] = 'Page life expectancy'
```

The recommended value of the PLE counter (in  seconds ) is greater than:

```
     total_memory_dedicated_for_sql_server / 4 * 300
```

Page Life Expectancy is the number of seconds a page will stay in the buffer pool without references. In simple words, if your page stays longer in the buffer pool (area of the memory cache) your PLE is higher, leading to higher performance as every time request comes there are chances it may find its data in the cache itself instead of going to the hard drive to read the data.

If PLE is't enough Increase memory and tune indexes and statistics.

3) Use SSD disks

With the cost of solid state disks (SSDs) going down, use the SSDs as a second tier of cache.

4) Use RAID 5 for the databases; and RAID 10 for the transaction logs and tempdb.

In general, the SQL optimizer game is moving data from disk (low speed) to cache (memory- high speed).

Increase memory and enhance diskIo speed, you gain high performance

Comment: Thank you M.Hassan for such a big answer! will try all your recommendations. Checking as accepted

Comment: Welcome and happy day.